# cocos2dx c++ appending a vector to a vector

Tags: cocos2d-x

How do I concatenate two cocos2d::Vector s?

```
cocos2d::Vector<FiniteTimeAction*> V1;
cocos2d::Vector<FiniteTimeAction*> V2;
```

I want to have V2 appended to V1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cocos2d::Vector has overloaded pushBack which takes a vector and pushing it back to another.

```
V1.pushBack(V2);
```

CCVector.h

```
    /** Adds a new element at the end of the Vector. */
    void pushBack(T object)
    {
        CCASSERT(object != nullptr, "The object should not be nullptr");
        _data.push_back( object );
        object->retain();
    }

    /** Push all elements of an existing Vector to the end of current Vector. */
    void pushBack(const Vector<T>& other)
    {
        for(const auto &obj : other) {
            _data.push_back(obj);
            obj->retain();
        }
    }
```

P.S what is unclear why they do not re use  pushBack(T object) in overloaded pushBack(const Vector& other)